# Dql code shows in website - Doctrine2/Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm

We are using Doctrine 2.4 with Codeigniter 3. In my endeavor to get it working I came across something strange.

When calling getRepository() or findAll() it also gives back the DQL string to the website. I have tried debugging it but haven't found where the DQL is shown.

Anyone know where this is printed?

The code:

```
public function showProductsTest()
{
    $productRepository = $this->em->getRepository('Entities\Product');
    $products = $productRepository->findAll();
    $prod = array();
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $prod[] = array($product->getID(), $product->getName());
    }

    return $prod;
}
```

The output shows:
[Doctrine DQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDP5D.png)

Comment: Found out that in Doctrine.php the library loader there was a function called $logger = new EchoSQLLogger; When this is disabled DQL disappeared.